# Field extension of complex root of cubic equation

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

> If $c$ is a complex root of a cubic $a(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$, show that $\mathbb{Q}(c)$ is the splitting field of $a(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

For this, we must show that $\mathbb{Q}(c)$ contains all three roots of $a(x)$. It certainly contains $c$.

There are two other roots of $a(x)$, one of which is real, and the other of which is the conjugate of $c$. Suppose $c=p+qi$, then $\overline{c}=p-qi=\dfrac{p^2+q^2}{p+qi}$, so $\overline{c}\in\mathbb{Q}(c)$. (Hmm... actually I just realized $p,q$ might not belong to $\mathbb{Q}$.. maybe trouble here)

What about the last root? We know that the sum of the three roots is a rational number.

Comment: Yes, you have trouble with $p,q$ there)

Comment: @user68061 Thanks for confirming.. any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: If you want to adjoin one root, then they are all algebraicaly equivalent. There is no advantage to choosing a complex root. The order of the reaulting field will be three. So, do you see the problem here?

Comment: @BillKleinhans You mean there is a problem because if we adjoin the real root, certainly the resulting field does not contain the complex roots. So the problem statement is false, right?

Comment: Yes, the statement is false. Consider polynomial $x^3-2$ and the root $\omega \sqrt[3]{2}$..

Comment: If the splitting field contains complex elements, then taking the complex conjugate is an isomorphism, of order two, which must be a subgroup of the full Galois group. So the order of the Galois group must be even.

Answer (score 1):

This is false, and in fact nearly the opposite is true: $\mathbb{Q}(c)$ is *never* the splitting field of $a(x)$ if $a(x)$ is irreducible.  Indeed, if $\mathbb{Q}(c)$ were the splitting field, then $\mathbb{Q}(d)$ would also be the splitting field for any other root $d$ of $a(x)$ (since $a(x)$ is irreducible so $\mathbb{Q}(c)\cong\mathbb{Q}[x]/(a(x))\cong\mathbb{Q}(d)$).  But if $d$ is the real root of $a(x)$, then $\mathbb{Q}(d)\subset\mathbb{R}$ so it cannot contain all the roots of $a(x)$.